# Why does Ubuntu split up my file path?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I had a small question concerning something in Ubuntu. I noticed that whenever I `cd` to a two-word place, Ubuntu seems to go there. However, when I mention the file path to this place, Ubuntu splits up the text.

[image: Here is the original cd, and, as seen, it can easily go to the specified area.][image: Yet, when I mention the file path to the place, it doesn't work.]

As seen, in the first picture, the system can go to the specified place. However, when I mention the file path to the two-word place, Ubuntu seems to split up the two words and search for either of them, which don't exist.

Can someone help?

Note: I have tried `''` instead of `""` around the file, but it still doesn't work. I am also using the Linux application on Windows (which, yes, I know is very dangerous).

Comment: Do quotes around the WHOLE dir and file please ;)

Comment: I learned a long time ago not to use spaces. I use CamelCase, under_score, or justalabel. Then you do not have the issue of escaping or quoting which can be somewhat different depending on where used.

Comment: It looks to me like the error is *within* your `jmf4.pl` script

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use quotation marks around the entire path, this is required when there are folder or filenames containing spaces.

Comment: The Wildcat " \ " can also be used. Example: `Natural\ Pediatrics`.

Answer (score 4):

Escape spaces in directory or filenames with `\` symbol. For example, to change directory to `~/Some Dir` use command

```
cd ~/Some\ Dir
```